# Unable to restore nested fragment state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm having a problem restoring the state of nested fragments. Here's the hierarchy:

`MainActivity`

----> `AlarmOverviewFragment` (doesn't really hold any important data)

--------> `AlarmFragment` (holds data)

The problem I am running into is when I minimize the app (press home button) and then reopen the app, it crashes every time when trying to get data from an array stored as one of `Fragment`'s instance variables inside of `onCreateView()`.

The frustrating bit is that I'm saving the instance variables in `onSaveInstanceState()`, but `savedInstanceState` is always null in `onCreateView()`, `onCreate()`, and `onActivityCreated()`.

Clearly I am missing something huge here because I've tried many solutions found on stackoverflow to no avail. Here's some relevant code bits:

#### Saving instance data:

```java
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("hour", this.hour);
    outState.putInt("window", this.window);
    outState.putInt("minutes", this.minutes);
    outState.putBooleanArray("days", this.days);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

#### Unsuccessfully trying to restore data

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        /* Never happens */
        hour = savedInstanceState.getInt("hour");
        window = savedInstanceState.getInt("window");
        minutes = savedInstanceState.getInt("minutes");
        days = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("days");
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        /* Also never happens */
    }
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

#### And just in case this is helpful, here's the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: group12.wakemeup, PID: 22756
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {group12.wakemeup/group12.wakemeup.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                      at group12.wakemeup.AlarmFragment.onCreateView(AlarmFragment.java:113)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6288)
                      at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6334)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6339)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3110)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

EDIT

#### Extra information

Each `AlarmFragment` is added dynamically and given a unique ID via `View.generateViewId()`, so I've been unsure of how to save each fragment in `MainActivity`. Also worth mentioning that I **do** use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to handle tabs/swiping (there are other Overview fragments in this app, but I left them out as they aren't causing me problems). I've heard there is a way to use a `ViewPager` to save state, perhaps there is one with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` as well?

Comment: `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState` won't be called automatically (unlike Activities). You need to get the Fragment.State from the Fragment and save it manually in the outBundle for your Activity and then handle the restore from your Activity,  or just use a ViewPager where it will save Fragment.State automatically

Comment: I use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` (added in edit), but I'm guessing it doesn't automatically save state given my problems. Is there a way I can use it to save state? Also, how would I save/restore fragment state from `MainActivity` if they are dynamically created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your problem seems different from the start, actually you don't need to re-create your fragments inside `onNewIntent` every time.
You can do this instead:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if ("some_action".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //your action, in your case create and assign fragment

        //remove the action
        intent.setAction(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to accept this instead of mine since I like what you did better. Thanks!

Comment: @sirstancake You're welcome. Let me know if there any problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your fragments in your activity

```
private YourFragment yourFragment;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Save the fragment instances
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "any string you want as key", yourFragment);
    //or use code below if you use android.support.v4.app.Fragment 
    //getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "any string you want as key", yourFragment);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //retrieve your fragment that saved from onSaveInstanceState()
        yourFragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "any string you want as key");
        //or
        //yourFragment = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "any string you want as key");
    }
    else {
        //create your fragment if it is first time
        yourFragment = new YourFragment();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem I foresee with this approach is that my Fragments are created dynamically. They **are** given a unique ID via `View.generateViewId` though. Is there a simple approach to saving the state of these fragments if they are created this way - such as in a loop? I guess I'm just not 100% sure how I would refer to them from `MainActivity`.

Comment: I suppose that `AlarmFragment` is inside `AlarmOverviewFragment`? Have you try to save `AlarmOverviewFragment`?

Comment: I haven't tried that only because the crash is caused inside `AlarmFragment`. If I save the state of a parent fragment, does that mean the child states are saved as well?

Comment: I can't make sure of that, but it is supposed to work like that. I mean you save the fragment itself instead of just the states.

Comment: It's not really working for me. I have each `__OverviewFragment` held in a `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of as individual instance variables in `MainActivity`, but this isn't solving the problem that each `AlarmFragment` is going through `onCreateView()` again with null values for its instance variables

Comment: How about if when you create your `FragmentPagerAdapter`, you don't need to create each `__OverviewFragment` directly from there. You can create each `__OverviewFragment` fragment in your `MainActivity`, and passing that fragments to your `FragmentPagerAdapter`. With this approach, you can get each instance of the fragments in your `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess my problem came from something completely different. `MainActivity` was creating a new `AlarmFragment` using `onNewIntent()` when it returned from a series of activities to define the values for each `AlarmFragment`. Evidently, minimizing the app and then reopening it calls `onNewIntent()` every time, so my solution was to make sure that I was actually creating new `AlarmFragments` with data. Stupid problem, stupid solution